# How to create a Qt-Quick Test

Tags: user-interface, qml, qtquick2, qttest

I have to create a Unit-Test.

But first, I´ve to get clear what to do.
There is a QtQuick2-App written and now I would like to do Unit-Tests with the GUI. What are the steps for Unit-Tests with GUI? After reading the Qt-documents, I could not create any ideas for starting with the test.

Hope somebody can help me.

**Edit**: I was able to run some tests, after adding `tst_button.qml` and `tst_test.cpp` to my Project (main.cpp is in comments now). Is this the right way, or should I create a new project just for the Tests? If yes, what kind of project is needed?
And the last question: Do I need to build up my `MainForm` for pressing buttons for example?

tst_button.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtTest 1.0

Rectangle{
    id: myRec
    property var myMainForm: null

    TestCase{
        name:"ButtonClick"
        when:windowShown

        function test_init(){
           var createMyWindow = "import QtQuick 2.0; MainForm{id:myForm}"
           var myMainForm = Qt.createQmlObject(createMyWindow,myRec)
            myRec.myMainForm = myMainForm
        }
      }
  }
```

tst_test.cpp

```
#include <QtQuickTest/quicktest.h>
QUICK_TEST_MAIN(test)
```

Comment: Take a look at [TestCase](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qttest-testcase.html#details)

Comment: Do I just add a *.qml file to my project and fill it with my code? If yes, what do I have to do to start the test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Testing and Debugging](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/testing-and-debugging.html) lists two ways:

> - [Qt Test (also known as testlib)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest-overview.html) - a framework for unit tests of C++ code
> - [Qt Quick Test](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-qtquicktest.html) - a framework for unit tests of QML code

You can use Qt Test for testing Qt Quick applications, but that's generally better for when you need access to C++ API that isn't available in QML.

> Do I just add a *.qml file to my project and fill it with my code? If yes, what do I have to do to start the test?

You'll first need to make the tests a separate project, unless you're planning on using [`qmltestrunner`](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/qml/tutorials/qml-unit-testing/) (I have no idea why that tool isn't documented by Qt itself).

The [Running Tests](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-qtquicktest.html#running-tests) section of Qt Quick Test's documentation details how to get a test up and running.

---

> I was able to run some tests, after adding tst_button.qml and tst_test.cpp to my Project (main.cpp is in comments now). Is this the right way, or should I create a new project just for the Tests?

If your application is pure QML and only intended to be run with `qmlscene`, for example, then doing it that way is fine. However, if you intend to deploy/ship your application, you'll probably need to have an executable, which means making separate projects for the application and the tests.

> If yes, what kind of project is needed?

You could have a [`SUBDIRS`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#subdirs) project, so that your tests and the application itself can all be opened at once in Qt Creator. Something like this:

```
myapp.pro
app/
    main.cpp
    app.pro
    resources.qrc
    main.qml
tests/
    tests.pro
    data/
        tst_stuff.qml
```

> And the last question: Do I need to build up my MainForm for pressing buttons for example?

No. The [`.ui` feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30653686/904422) is just a format that allows Qt Creator to enforce certain constraints to make it easier to design Qt Quick UIs with Qt Quick Designer. `MainForm.ui.qml` is therefore just a convenience. If you already have an existing component in QML, you can create instances of that and test it.

Comment: Thanks for your support, could you have a look at my edits?

Comment: What kind of project is `tests.pro`? How do you create it with Qt Creator?

Comment: Ah, Qt Quick Test projects are available under Creator 4.6, under "Auto Test Project" then select "Qt Quick Test" for framework.