# Qt QML Desktop application automation testing

Tags: c++, qt, automated-tests, qml, qtquick2

I have a task to automate Qt QML based desktop applications through open source frameworks. I am completely new to testing and also to Qt QML. I am good with Java and Python and also Javascript.

1. Can someone please suggest a way to write automation tests for Qt QML desktop application?
2. Can I code things to read the elements and widgets in the Qt QML applications?, So I can validate various cases.
3. If so, are there any tutorials or sample automation test projects for Qt QML applications?

Comment: Check QML [TestCase](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qttest-testcase.html#details)

Comment: [How to create a Qt-Quick Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210134/how-to-create-a-qt-quick-test)

Comment: Thanks @MohammadKanan, these seems to be for unit tests that comes within applications. Is there any way to write tests for the application in a separate project?. So that I can run the tests externally

Comment: External application to "read elements and widgets"?

Comment: Yes, that will be very helpful, If can code some tests on the read elements and widgets  @MohammadKanan

Comment: Take a look at [Squish](https://www.froglogic.com/squish/editions/qt-gui-test-automation/)

Comment: Squish seems to be a licensed one. Can I use any of the open source framework? - @GrecKo

Comment: On which platforms do you want to test? If you can afford the license, I would suggest Squish.

Comment: I want to test in windows platform. I could not afford for license

Comment: Does someone have done this through open source?, Looking forward for an answer

Comment: I am also looking for an answer. There's a Qt webdriver for Selenium available here: https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [Spix](https://github.com/faaxm/spix). Once you link against it, you can remote control your QML UI by sending fake events, either from C++, or from a script using RPC. Any scripting language that supports XML-RPC, like python, can be used.
This way, you can automate and test your Qt/QML application.

Objects are identified by paths, so you don't have to deal with coordinates. [Spix](https://github.com/faaxm/spix) finds the item by the `objectName` property set in QML.
You can also query object properties from the script...

The library is fairly new and under development, but I think it already covers a lot of the more common use cases in desktop apps...