# QML-How to add another command to onClick in ui.qml?

Tags: qt, onclick, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I want to add another command to `itemDelegate.onClick` .

Here is my code:

```
ListView {
        id: beam_viewer
        x: 8
        y: 18
        width: 188
        height: 374
        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            id: delegate_item
            width: 180
            height: 25
            Text {
                text: modelData
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }
            onClicked: img_footprint.source = applicationPath +
                       "footprints/" + modelData + ".webp"


        }
    }
```

I use `onClicked` for change my image source and I want to use `modelData`  for myText.text . I use ui.qml and it doesn't allow to use { } after onClicked because it reject using `javascript`.

How can I add to onClicked `myText.text = modelData`.

Thank you!

Comment: I can't run your example, but I can't see any reason, why {} should not be allowed. AFAIK: Already in your example, you utilize JS (= as opposed to : )  
If it does not work with the {} try call a function, in which you do all the stuff you want.

Comment: `{}` are allowed as you can see here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html

Comment: What does `reject using javascript` means? What was an error? There is no problem to group commands inside {}. Probably you didn't post your actual code. Anyway, read the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html).

Comment: OP is talking about Qt Quick Designer rejecting the JavaScript because it can't deal with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652537/what-is-the-use-of-the-ui-qml-files-in-qt5-qml/30653686#30653686

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to move the code that uses JavaScript (e.g. the contents of the `ItemDelegate` that contains the `Text` item and whatnot) into its own .QML file that Qt Quick Designer can't see. For example:

**MainForm.ui.qml**:

```
ListView {
    id: beam_viewer
    x: 8
    y: 18
    width: 188
    height: 374
    delegate: MyDelegate {}
}
```

**MyDelegate.qml**:

```
ItemDelegate {
    id: delegate_item
    width: 180
    height: 25
    Text {
        text: modelData
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    }
    onClicked: img_footprint.source = applicationPath +
               "footprints/" + modelData + ".webp"
}
```

Personally I just wouldn't use `ui.qml` files. I know that's not a very satisfying answer, but it seems to just slow me down.