# What is a standard (Qt) way to create single ui.qml file?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

In Qt app [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-contactlist-example.html), they use single `*.ui.qml` form files. I understand everything but I was used to creating 2 files, for example, `Contact.qml` and `ContactForm.ui.qml`, instead of one `ContactForm.ui.qml`. Now if I want to create such a single form file, I have/see two options:

1. While creating standard **QML file (Qt Quick 2)**, I give name and whole `.ui.qml` extension.
2. I create **QtQuick Ui File** (which creates 2 files) and delete one (business logic) file.

For me, both options seem to be workarounds, not the *Qt way*. Could you show me the *Qt way*?

Answer (score 2):

(Casually, you can open not only `.ui.qml` but any qml file in *design* mode if you follow the roles [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652537/what-is-the-use-of-the-ui-qml-files-in-qt5-qml?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)).

The list of wizards seen when *adding new* in Creator, are the standard wizards that Qt probably thinks are sufficient and suitable with a general perspective.

**Qt offers a solution** though ... you can add your own **custom wizard** to the list of standard wizards in Qt Creator, following Qt documentation [Adding New Custom Wizards](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards.html) creation procedure, so you can add more to existing wizards.

Specifically for `.ui.qml` only (without the qml file) creation, the section [Adding JSON-Based Wizards](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards-json.html) in the above documentation works just fine, for example:

- Start Creator from command line **with verbose option**:
  `Qt_base\Tools\QtCreator\bin>qtcreator.exe -customwizard-verbose`
- In *Tools, Options, Keyboard* ... filter by *Factory.Reset* and fill up a new **short cut**, if one does not exist, for example `Ctrl+Alt+F10`
- In folder *C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\share\qtcreator\templates\wizards\classes* ... copy the wizard folder used to create `.ui.qml` **qtquickui** and rename it to any name.
- Now and most important, inside the new folder, edit the wizard *json* file to customize your new wizard ..

(1) Give new `id` following roles described in the link

(2) under *options* remove the option for adding qml file along with the form.

(3) under *pages*, remove the field that prompts for qml file name.

(4) in section `"name": "FormClass"`, modify `"trText": "%{Class}Form"` to `"trText": "Form"`

(5) under *generators* , remove the qml file generator and keep the `.ui.qml` file generator.

- After editing is completed, you can now activate the new wizard, to do that press the short cut created above (`Ctrl+Alt+F10`) and that's all! you should now see your new wizard when you go *Add new* under *Qt* section ...

Here is modified version of *wizard.json*

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "supportedProjectTypes": [ ],
    "id": "S.QtQuickUi",
    "category": "R.Qt",
    "trDescription": "Creates a Qt Quick Designer UI form along with a matching QML file for implementation purposes. You can add the form and file to an existing Qt Quick Project.",
    "trDisplayName": "QtQuick UI File Only",
    "trDisplayCategory": "Qt",
    "iconText": "ui.qml",
    "featuresRequired": [ "QtSupport.Wizards.FeatureQtQuick.UiFiles" ],
    "enabled": "%{JS: [ %{Plugins} ].indexOf('QmlJSEditor') >= 0}",

    "options" : [
        { "key": "UiFile", "value": "%{FormClass}.%{JS: Util.preferredSuffix('application/x-qt.ui+qml')}" }
    ],

    "pages" :
    [
        {
            "trDisplayName": "Define Class",
            "trShortTitle": "Details",
            "typeId": "Fields",
            "data" :
            [

                {
                    "name": "FormClass",
                    "trDisplayName": "Component form name:",
                    "mandatory": true,
                    "type": "LineEdit",
                    "data": {
                        "validator": "(?:[A-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*|)",
                        "fixup": "%{JS: '%{INPUT}'.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + '%{INPUT}'.slice(1) }",
                        "trText": "Form"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "TargetPath",
                    "type": "PathChooser",
                    "trDisplayName": "Path:",
                    "mandatory": true,
                    "data":
                    {
                        "kind": "existingDirectory",
                        "basePath": "%{InitialPath}",
                        "path": "%{InitialPath}"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "trDisplayName": "Project Management",
            "trShortTitle": "Summary",
            "typeId": "Summary"
        }
    ],
    "generators" :
    [
        {
            "typeId": "File",
            "data": [
                {
                    "source": "fileForm.ui.qml.tpl",
                    "target": "%{TargetPath}/%{UiFile}",
                    "openInEditor": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This just seems like a missing feature in Creator. Go with option #1 since it's less work, and report a suggestion/bug that there should be a way to create standalone .ui.qml files.